# Dynamic class regarding the route path

Tags: vue.js

With Vue 2.6, I have a link rendered with router-link, like this:

```
<router-link class="nav-link" to="/about" v-if="isLogged"><i class="fas fa-sun"></i> About</router-link>
```

Regarding the value of the route `{{ $route.path }}`, I would like to add a class to obtain a render like this:

```
<router-link class="nav-link active" to="/about" v-if="isLogged"><i class="fas fa-sun"></i> About</router-link>
```

See the word "active" added.

How to do that? I tried a lot of things following the [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Array-Syntax), without success.

Comment: Are you familiar with the fact that an active router-link automatically gets assigned the .router-link-active class?

Comment: Thanks crosen for your answer. I did not know that (I am a beginner in Vue. And I just saw that I can setup the class name I want in the constructor of the router, like that : const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes,
  **linkExactActiveClass: "active",**
})

Answer (score 1):

Vue does this automatically for you: https://router.vuejs.org/api/#active-class.

However, if you still want to apply your own active class you can bind it using `v-bind`:

```
<router-link class="nav-link" :class="{ 'active': $route.path === '/about' }" to="/about" v-if="isLogged"><i class="fas fa-sun"></i> About</router-link>
```

This way it evaluates the truthiness of the condition on the right of the colon and, if `true`, applies the class given on the left.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax

Comment: fyi, `:class` is a shorthand for `v-bind:class`